# In the differential $da_{ring}=\pi(r+dr)^2-\pi r^2 = 2\pi r dr+\pi(dr)^2$ why can we ignore $(dr)^2$ as $dr \to 0$?

Tags: limits, differential

Consider a thin uniform disc of mass M and radius R.

I am interested in the calculation of moment of inertia about an axis passing through the center of mass, perpendicular to the disc, specifically using area elements in the integral that are thin rings of radius $r$ and width $dr$.

If you would like to see the exact calculation I am following, it is [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/readings/MIT8_01F16_chapter16.3_16.4.pdf) one from an MIT OCW course, page 4. It is a physics course, but I am interested in the mathematical aspect of the integral.

We want to calculate

$$\int_{disc}{r_{dm}^2 dm}$$

where

$$dm=\frac{M}{\pi R^2}da_{ring}$$

My question regards $da_{ring}$

$$da_{ring}=\pi(r+dr)^2-\pi r^2 = 2\pi r dr+\pi(dr)^2$$

> In the limit that $dr\to 0$ the term proportional to $(dr)^2$ can be
> ignored and the area is $da=2\pi r dr$

What is the technical reason why we can ignore the term proportional to $(dr)^2$?

Comment: This has definitely been asked before. "Dividing" by $dr$ we get $\frac{dA}{dr} = 2 \pi r + \pi dr$, and $dr \to 0$ as $r \to 0$.

Comment: I get the "arithmetic" of it. I am looking for interpretations of what it means, since what I am actually plugging into the integral is $dA$. As $dr \to 0$, we obtain the derivative of area $2\pi r$. So of course, the rate of change of area relative to radius times a small increment (differential) in r gives us the change in area. But what is it technically that impedes us from achieving the same result in the $dA$ equation. Ie, what is it about the assumptions in using limits with differentials that is perhaps not met?

Comment: The answer lies in nonstandard analysis, where we can treat $dr$ as an infinitesimal quantity on its own, rather than being part of an expression such as $\frac{dA}{dr}$. Here is an example of this in action: [How do you find the derivative of $x\sqrt{x}$ with nonstandard analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151315).

Comment: I don't believe it's useful to know the technical reason why you can ignore $(dr)^2$. Would you like some intuition instead?

Comment: @TobyMak Sure, intuition is great as well. My intuition would be that if we define an area function $A(r)=\pi r^2$, the linear approximation to the function is a line described by $\Delta A=2\pi r \Delta r=$. We can also use a second order approximation $\Delta A = 2\pi r \Delta r + \pi (\Delta r)^2$. If we consider the ratio between the second order and first order terms in that approximation, we see that as $\Delta r$ goes to zero, the ratio goes to zero too.

Comment: Do you have an alternative intuition? In fact, I am asking about the technical reason because though I use calculus a lot, I am always bothered by the fact that I don't quite know the actual "fundamental" reasons why I can do certain things with differentials in integrals. So I would like to know what are the mathematical topics/subjects/fields I would need to study to really "know" about differentials.